# Why do ophiolites obduce upon Continental Crust?

Tags: plate-tectonics, crust

Oceanic Crust is more dense than continental one. The margin between both types of materials can be passive or develop a subduction zone, where Oceanic Crust sinks under continental one.

I know there is geological evidence of cases where Oceanic Crust obduce upon the continent.

How can it happen if Oceanic Crust is more dense?

Comment: This paper https://doi.org/10.1080/00206814.2016.1276482 would be a good start

Comment: @Gimelist thanks for sharing. From a previous discussion when I was bad I cannot read it, only the abstract. I realized my mom has a Science Direct license at University but she will get retired next year. I think it is not possible if there is no a volcanic arc-island and a polarity reversal from subduction to convergent margin from the abstract and from what I have read at Wikipedia.